# Instantiating IdentityMapper got ClassException. How to use IdentityMapper?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have 2 jobs. The first job just executes map tasks [1] and does not execute the reduce tasks. This forces that the map output will be saved in the HDFS.

After this job finishes, I will run another job that has the identity mapper class [2] that will read the map output produced from the previous job execution, and produce the same map output. I have set the identity mapper to the job in [3], but I get the error in [4].

I think that the reason of this problem is that the `setMapperClass(Class<? extends Mapper> cls)` is from different type of `IdentityMapper` [5].

How I use the `IdentityMapper`?

[1] Map class of the first job

```
public static class MyMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }

    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
                map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
            }
        } finally {
            cleanup(context);
        }
    }
}
```

[2] Identity class:

```
public static class MyFullyIndentityMapper extends IdentityMapper<Text, IntWritable> {}
```

[3] I set the identity class to the mapper.

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(MyWordCount.class);
conf.setJobName("wordcount");
conf.setClass("mapreduce.job.map.identity.class", MyFullyIndentityMapper.class, IdentityMapper.class);
Class<? extends IdentityMapper> identityClass = (Class<? extends IdentityMapper>) conf.getClass("mapreduce.job.map.identity.class", IdentityMapper.class);
job.setMapperClass(identityClass.asSubclass(Mapper.class));
```

[4] Error that I get:

```
Output path: /output1
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.examples.MyWordCount$MyFullyIndentityMapper
at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
```

[5] Identity mapper

```
public class IdentityMapper<K, V> extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<K, V, K, V> {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand why you are complicating things in the below code snippet

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(MyWordCount.class);
conf.setJobName("wordcount");
conf.setClass("mapreduce.job.map.identity.class", MyFullyIndentityMapper.class, IdentityMapper.class);
Class<? extends IdentityMapper> identityClass = (Class<? extends IdentityMapper>) conf.getClass("mapreduce.job.map.identity.class", IdentityMapper.class);
job.setMapperClass(identityClass.asSubclass(Mapper.class));
```

Do not set any mapper class.

```
job.setMapperClass(identityClass.asSubclass(Mapper.class));
```

Just comment out the above line.
MapReduce framework will by default run the IdentityMapper.

The above is my understanding of your question. I may have mis understood your question.